# Deleting UITableView Room error

Tags: uitableview, core-data, xcode7

I am getting the follow error when trying to delete a TableView item.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I am using the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

if editingStyle == .Delete {

    let roomToDelete : House = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! House
    moc.deleteObject(roomToDelete)

    do {
        try moc.save()
      } catch {
        print("Failed to save upon delete")
        return
     }

   tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
   self.tableView.reloadData()

   }

}
```

If I leave the last two lines of code off then I do not get the error, BUT the line does not delete because I am only removing the data from Core Data.  If I leave the table and return the line is gone.  I assume the error is because I am somehow not linking the line removal with the number of rows in section so there is a mismatch.  All of the searches I have done come back with similar programming to what I have.

Comment: Have you set the delegate for the FRC and implemented the associated methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by -

1) Removing

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

from the commit editing style function AND

2)  Adding

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

to the end of the viewDidLoad function

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting your view controller as the FRC delegate and using the delegate methods to update the table view. As the FRC is your data source it must know about the deletion in order to update the row count.

In your commit method you should just be deleting the object from the context. You should not delete the row from the table or reload the table (that should be done by the FRC delegate methods).